# Integral of exponential of trig function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, bessel-functions

Mathematica and Matlab are both failing me on this integral. I am trying to find alternative forms to be able to use numerical integration in a stable form.

I think I could re-write this potentially in terms of Bessel functions or Taylor expansions?
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\left(a\cos(x)^2 + b\sin(x)^2\right)}dx
$$

Comment: Try to turn the integrand into $a(x)+b(x)i$ form

Comment: What do you mean by this? How would I split the i term from being multiplied by both?

Comment: $e^{i(a\cdot\cos^2(x)+b\cdot\sin^2(x))}=\cos(a\cdot\cos^2(x)+b\cdot\sin^2(x))+i\cdot\sin(a\cdot\cos^2(x)+b\cdot\sin^2(x))$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both real and nonnegative, then I note that you actually only need to handle this integral after you simplify with $sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$. The effect is to leave an integral that can be written as a special value of the $J$-Bessel function.

Comment: Without any change of the formulation, Mathematica returns $$2 \pi  e^{\frac{1}{2} i (a+b)} J_0\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$